# DBCC CheckDB require how much size of the Tempdb

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

An automatic job running  to do the **DBCC CheckDB for all of our database on SQL Server 2008 R2**.

we have 22 DBs, and 1 of the db has about 160GB, I relocate a hard drive around 70 GB for the tempdb but it failed.

```
CheckDB Error : 1105 : Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage:  172324227579904' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup. [SQLSTATE 01000]
```

I would like to know how much size I need for this db check.

After using the **Estimateonly**  check, it only gives me an answer 45MB....which is a bug in MS SQL SEVER 2008 R2, so I try to connect to the database via SQL Serever 2012 and lanch the Estimateonly but the same answer.

Any guy could help me about how to get the exact size I need for a big DB DBCC check?

Sincerely

Comment: Can you apply latest service pack(if you are not on it) and see if you are getting the same estimates

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I will contact our IT-Operation team to do the update.

Comment: Besides it, May I ask why the SQL Server 2012 not working either?

Answer (score 0):

For more information. 
@TheGameiswar. I did a check on our SQL Server Pack. we already have the latest version of the SQL Server...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1B9D.png)

Comment: That information should be put in the comment section or you could edit your question.

Comment: Ah. OK. I thought after 2 minutes it is not able to edit the comment.

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Comment: Not really.  I checked my sql server version, it has the latest service package. but dbcc checkdb estimatonly return wrong answer still